# Not able to find material in MM60

Tags: odata, sap-erp

I have added a plant code to a material using ODATA API. I have used the following one:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/18fe3fab96864826bfa0be0de4f65b85/155d35580596a007e10000000a441470.html

However, when I go to MM60 screen, I don't see the material under the plant code.

What wrong am I doing? Is there a different way to get the plant details added through ODATA?